# What is the best way to test on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm "new" to Ruby on Rails and i just want to know what are the best practices to test in rails, what to use, how, etc.

If you drop some tutorial links that you think they're good.

Answer (score 1):

## Rspec

- **Pros:** I prefer Rspec, because it is very organized. You can describe a method, then create a context to execute it, and test it does what you expect. The specs (testing files) are automatically generated (eg when you generate a model), same as minitest.
- **Cons:** You have to learn a lot more.
- **Doc:** https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

## Minitest

- **Pros:** The default tests in rails are Minitest. They're automatically generated, and there's more documentation about them I think. Rails gem is tested with minitest. It is very simple and easy to learn.
- **Cons:** But in my opinion, tests are difficult to organize, and you could tend to repeat yourself.
- **Doc:** https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

You can use Minitest Specs, that are similar to Rspec, but it has become
hard to me to use them.

---

You could use **Cucumber** to let non-developers know what the App is doing in your tests.